# How to full the width of content of a row using bootstrap

Tags: css, angular, angular2-template, angular2-components

Hi All can someone help me with the Web App I'm creating.

Here is the screenshot [Web App Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zo0kU.png) of web app so far i want to Maximize the Creative Tim Material Dashboard Content

I want to Maximize the Text Converter card

Actually there is an Angualar template like this.

But i'm learning Web Development using Angular. I learn by solving error and doing things than learning by reading.

So i use the bootstrap template then applied it in the Angular app.

This is the code for the dashboard

```
<body class="">
  <div class="wrapper ">
    <div class="sidebar" data-color="purple" data-background-color="white" data-image="../assets/img/sidebar-1.jpg">
      <!--
        Tip 1: You can change the color of the sidebar using: data-color="purple | azure | green | orange | danger"

        Tip 2: you can also add an image using data-image tag
    -->
      <div class="logo">
        <a href="http://www.creative-tim.com" class="simple-text logo-normal">
          Creative Tim
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="sidebar-wrapper">
        <ul class="nav">
            <app-nav></app-nav> 

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main-panel">
      <!-- Navbar -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-transparent navbar-absolute fixed-top ">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-wrapper">
            <a class="navbar-brand">Dashboard</a>
          </div>


        </div>
      </nav>
      <!-- End Navbar -->
      <div class="content">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">

              <router-outlet></router-outlet>

          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

And the code for the textconverter component

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header card-header-primary">
          <h4 class="card-title">Text Converter</h4>
          <p class="card-category">(Multiline to Single line) or (Single line to Multiline)</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <form>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="bmd-label-floating">Fist Name</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="bmd-label-floating">Last Name</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Update Profile</button>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

but why does it not full screen? Even if i use the class `class="col-lg-12"`

But when the code is using two div class like in the code below.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header card-header-primary">
          <h4 class="card-title">Text Converter</h4>
          <p class="card-category">(Multiline to Single line) or (Single line to Multiline)</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <form>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="bmd-label-floating">Fist Name</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="bmd-label-floating">Last Name</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Update Profile</button>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-2">
        <div class="card card-profile">
          <div class="card-avatar">
            <a href="#pablo">
              <img class="img" src="../assets/img/faces/marc.jpg" />
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h6 class="card-category text-gray">CEO / Co-Founder</h6>
            <h4 class="card-title">Alec Thompson</h4>
            <p class="card-description">
              Don't be scared of the truth because we need to restart the human foundation in truth And I love you like Kanye loves Kanye I love Rick Owens’ bed design but the back is...
            </p>
            <a href="#pablo" class="btn btn-primary btn-round">Follow</a>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

It became like this.
It became full screen. Please see the screenshot below:

[Full Screen row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KeVeI.png)

Update:

Here is the code from the css class

```
.card {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-width: 0;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-clip: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}

.card>hr {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.card>.list-group:first-child .list-group-item:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 0.25rem;
  border-top-right-radius: 0.25rem;
}

.card>.list-group:last-child .list-group-item:last-child {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0.25rem;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0.25rem;
}

.card-body {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  padding: 1.25rem;
}

.card-title {
  margin-bottom: 0.75rem;
}

.card-subtitle {
  margin-top: -0.375rem;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.card-text:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.card-link:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.card-link+.card-link {
  margin-left: 1.25rem;
}

.card-header {
  padding: 0.75rem 1.25rem;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;
}

.card-header:first-child {
  border-radius: calc(0.25rem - 1px) calc(0.25rem - 1px) 0 0;
}

.card-header+.list-group .list-group-item:first-child {
  border-top: 0;
}

.card-footer {
  padding: 0.75rem 1.25rem;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-top: 1px solid #eeeeee;
}

.card-footer:last-child {
  border-radius: 0 0 calc(0.25rem - 1px) calc(0.25rem - 1px);
}

.card-header-tabs {
  margin-right: -0.625rem;
  margin-bottom: -0.75rem;
  margin-left: -0.625rem;
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.card-header-pills {
  margin-right: -0.625rem;
  margin-left: -0.625rem;
}

.card-img-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1.25rem;
}

.card-img {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: calc(0.25rem - 1px);
}

.card-img-top {
  width: 100%;
  border-top-left-radius: calc(0.25rem - 1px);
  border-top-right-radius: calc(0.25rem - 1px);
}

.card-img-bottom {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: calc(0.25rem - 1px);
  border-bottom-left-radius: calc(0.25rem - 1px);
}

.card-deck {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.card-deck .card {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .card-deck {
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
  }
  .card-deck .card {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 0 0%;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: 15px;
  }
}

.card-group {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.card-group>.card {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .card-group {
    flex-flow: row wrap;
  }
  .card-group>.card {
    flex: 1 0 0%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  .card-group>.card+.card {
    margin-left: 0;
    border-left: 0;
  }
  .card-group>.card:first-child {
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  }
  .card-group>.card:first-child .card-img-top,
  .card-group>.card:first-child .card-header {
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
  }
  .card-group>.card:first-child .card-img-bottom,
  .card-group>.card:first-child .card-footer {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  }
  .card-group>.card:last-child {
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  }
  .card-group>.card:last-child .card-img-top,
  .card-group>.card:last-child .card-header {
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
  }
  .card-group>.card:last-child .card-img-bottom,
  .card-group>.card:last-child .card-footer {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  }
  .card-group>.card:only-child {
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
  }
  .card-group>.card:only-child .card-img-top,
  .card-group>.card:only-child .card-header {
    border-top-left-radius: 0.25rem;
    border-top-right-radius: 0.25rem;
  }
  .card-group>.card:only-child .card-img-bottom,
  .card-group>.card:only-child .card-footer {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0.25rem;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0.25rem;
  }
  .card-group>.card:not(:first-child):not(:last-child):not(:only-child) {
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  .card-group>.card:not(:first-child):not(:last-child):not(:only-child) .card-img-top,
  .card-group>.card:not(:first-child):not(:last-child):not(:only-child) .card-img-bottom,
  .card-group>.card:not(:first-child):not(:last-child):not(:only-child) .card-header,
  .card-group>.card:not(:first-child):not(:last-child):not(:only-child) .card-footer {
    border-radius: 0;
  }
}

.card-columns .card {
  margin-bottom: 0.75rem;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .card-columns {
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 1.25rem;
  }
  .card-columns .card {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

What do i need to change in the code?

Thank you

Comment: Could you share some of the css you use for the `.card` class? It's unclear whether the issue is with the bootstrap columns or with the card element not adjusting its width accordingly.

Comment: @G1N Hi. I updated the question and added the code for the .card class